# Why Range.getBoundingClientRect() returns 0 for range inside textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, range, getboundingclientrect

I have `<textarea>` element and create range inside it:

- Create new range via `document.createRange()`
- Get the only child node of `<textarea>` via `textarea.childNodes[0]`
- Set range start and range end via `range.setStart` and `range.setEnd`

Then I call `range.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
let node = textarea.childNodes[0];

let range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(node, 3);
range.setEnd(node, 5);
console.log(range.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```html
<textarea>aa bb cc</textarea>
```

But I receive `ClientRect` object with all zero fields, that is `left = top = width = height = 0`. Why these fields are zeros?

---

Note that all works fine if I replace `<textarea>` with usual div:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('div');
let node = textarea.childNodes[0];

let range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(node, 3);
range.setEnd(node, 5);
console.log(range.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```html
<div>aa bb cc</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<textarea>` is a [replacement element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

> Objects inserted using the CSS content property are anonymous replaced
>   elements. They are "anonymous" because they don't exist in the HTML
>   markup.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but why if I replace <textarea> with usual <div> all works as expected? Please see update to question

Comment: `<textarea>` is a [replacement element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), _"Objects inserted using the CSS content property are anonymous replaced elements. They are "anonymous" because they don't exist in the HTML markup."_

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no simple way to modify my code in order to it returns non zero for textarea?

Comment: You can use `<div>` element with `contentEditiable` attribute set

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate? `<textarea>` is not mentioned anywhere on that page, nor does it have any similarity with any of the mentioned elements, nor does it have anything to do with CSS `content`. In fact, the `<textarea>` content is contained in the document directly as a text node, and can be queried and selected like any other part of the document. If there is some reason, this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do it:

https://jh3y.medium.com/how-to-where-s-the-caret-getting-the-xy-position-of-the-caret-a24ba372990a

You need to create a div, copy all styles of the input element into that div, copy text up to the selection into that div, add a span inside that div with the selection and then you can measure this span relative to the div before removing the div again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly robust "caret position listener" that works for text areas and that was originally based on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/audinue/pen/EogPqQ). It uses a "shadow" element with the textarea's styles copied across, and it handles the case where the textarea is resized, and also if it is removed from the DOM. There are also various small issues that need to be handled, which you can see by reading the code (`phantomNewline` in particular).

```js
function trackCaretPosition(textArea, callback) {
  const copy = createCopy(textArea);
  copy.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Hide the shadow element

  function updateShadowPositionAndSize() {
    let rect = textArea.getBoundingClientRect();
    let scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    copy.style.left = `${rect.left + scrollLeft}px`;
    copy.style.top = `${rect.top + scrollTop}px`;
    copy.style.width = `${textArea.offsetWidth}px`;
    copy.style.height = `${textArea.offsetHeight}px`;
    copy.scrollTop = textArea.scrollTop;
  }

  function update() {
    updateShadowPositionAndSize();
    const position = getCaretPosition(textArea, copy);
    callback(position);
  }

  textArea.addEventListener('input', update);
  textArea.addEventListener('click', update);
  textArea.addEventListener('scroll', update);
  textArea.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(["ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown"].includes(e.key)) {
      update();
    }
  });

  // Resize shadow if textarea is resized:
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => updateShadowPositionAndSize());
  resizeObserver.observe(textArea);

  // Remove shadow if textarea is removed:
  const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for(const mutation of mutations) {
      if(Array.from(mutation.removedNodes).includes(textArea)) {
        copy.remove();
        mutationObserver.disconnect();
        resizeObserver.disconnect();
      }
    }
  });
  mutationObserver.observe(textArea.parentNode, { childList: true });

  function createCopy(textArea) {
    const copy = document.createElement('div');
    const style = getComputedStyle(textArea);

    const propertiesToCopy = ['overflow-x', 'overflow-y', 'display', 'font-family', 'font-size', 'font-weight', 'word-wrap', 'white-space', 'padding-left', 'padding-right', 'padding-top', 'padding-bottom', 'border-left-width', 'border-top-width', 'border-right-width', 'border-bottom-width', 'border-style', 'text-align'];
    propertiesToCopy.forEach(key => copy.style[key] = style[key]);

    Object.assign(copy.style, {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: `${textArea.offsetLeft}px`,
      top: `${textArea.offsetTop}px`,
    });

    document.body.appendChild(copy);
    return copy;
  }

  function getCaretPosition(textArea, copy) {
    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textArea;
    const value = textArea.value;
    let phantomNewline = false;
  
    // We need a 'phantom' character for final newline due to difference between HTML vs textarea handling
    if(selectionStart === selectionEnd && value[selectionStart - 1] === '\n') {
      phantomNewline = true;
    }
  
    copy.textContent = phantomNewline ? value.substring(0, selectionStart) + ' ' + value.substring(selectionStart) : value;
  
    if(!copy.firstChild) {
      const style = getComputedStyle(textArea);
      return {
        x: textArea.offsetLeft + parseFloat(style.paddingLeft),
        y: textArea.offsetTop + parseFloat(style.paddingTop),
      };
    }
  
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(copy.firstChild, phantomNewline ? selectionStart + 1 : selectionStart);
    range.setEnd(copy.firstChild, phantomNewline ? selectionEnd + 1 : selectionEnd);
  
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    return {
      x: rect.left + scrollLeft,
      y: rect.top + scrollTop,
    };
  }

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```js
trackCaretPosition(textareaEl, pos => {
  console.log(`Caret is at: x=${pos.x}, y=${pos.y}`);
});
```